# Determine the maximum percentage that circle $R$ can take up of circle $H$

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

Consider circle, $H$, with radius $h$. A smaller circle, $F$, with radius $f$, is position such that it's curve passes through the centre of $H$ but it is not contained entirely within the circumference of $H$. Inside $F$ exists an isosceles triangle with two side lengths equaling $f$. Inscribed within this triangle is a circle, $R$, with radius $r$.

Given that $R$ must be contained entirely within the circumference of $H$, find the maximum percentage that $R$ can take up of the area of circle $H$.

(Note: The following image isn't necessarily the correct relative sizes of circles $F$ and $R$ for $R$ to have the largest possible area. This is just here to act as a visual aid)
[image]

Comment: Find $r$ in terms of $f$ and consider the maximum value for $f$

Comment: @DanielMathias After having a break from this question and finally having more time to sit down and give it another crack, I think I've worked out the solution. Considering the only restraint on $F$ is that it needs to be smaller than $H$, the maximum value for $f$ would be where $f$ is only infinitesimally smaller than $h$, so effectively where $f$=$h$. After going through all the calculations with this assumption I arrived with the conclusion that the final percentage that $R$ takes up of $H$ should equal $2\left(5\sqrt{5}-11\right)f^{2} = 2\left(5\sqrt{5}-11\right)h^{2}=9.01699\text{%}$